# xcode iphone simulator view smaller than storyboard

Tags: iphone, xcode, size, storyboard, simulator

I'm having issues with the size of my story board and the size of the actual display on the iPhone Simulator.  Any ideas?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your simulator is proper. No need to resize it.

You only need to follow these steps

```
 1. go to nib/storyboard.
 2. click on view
 3. check menu on right side
 4. go to 4th tab
 5. Expand Simulated Metrics
 6. Check Status bar is equal to Default
 7. Top Bar & Bottom Bar are equal to None & None respectively.
```

Enjoy Programming!

Comment: changed to the indicated values, cleaned and rebuilt, same problem.

Comment: ok. then set Topbar from none to Navigation Bar & set Bottombar from none to Tab Bar. Then design your interface accordingly. After designing set bottombar & topbar to none again

Comment: Hmmm...this did the trick.  Thanks for the tip.  Seems a bit cumbersome though.  Any way to have the storyboard default layout be classic?

Comment: in the same 4th tab.. change "Size" to Retina 3.5 or Retina 4. Or.. you have a new small button near zoom (-) (+) button

Comment: @TonyMkenu : Does this message intended for me?

Comment: sorry, no.. was for @Grymjack at his comm: "Any way to have the storyboard default layout be classic?"

Answer (score 6):

There are many correct answers to this question, but the thing is that you can do that by pressing a single button. I had the same problem and this is how I managed to solve it:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your storyboard is using the iPhone 5 screen size. To change your simulator to use the iPhone 5 emulator, goto the simulator and click on Hardware > Device > iPhone (Retina 4 inch).

Comment: tried this, got extra sized simulator, but same overlap problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your storyboard view is for iPhone 5 but your simulator is iPhone classic. Try changing the simulator to iPhone 5. And if you want to work this view for iPhone classic then try changing the autoresizing for the the two buttons.

Comment: I would like to have the storyboard set to classic size but I'm not seeing where I can change the 'autosizing' for the two buttons?  :(

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck **use Autolayout**  from file inspector

**1. go to nib.**

**2. click on view**

**3. go to 1st tab**

**4. Uncheck use Autolayout**

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer on how to keep the display at the regular size without having to add and then remove the bars for every screen.  I will have to steal part of an earlier answer:

1. go to nib/storyboard.
2. click on view
3. check menu on right side
4. go to 4th tab
5. Expand Simulated Metrics
6. Change the 'size' value to 'Retina 3.5 Full Screen'.

That makes the storyboard layout the same size as the IPhone simulator.

Comment: @a1phanumeric - this is actually the same as your answer, just attacking it from the other side.

Answer (score 0):

For me, Xcode seemed to fire up the iOS Simulator viewing the iPhone 4 model by default. Maybe there's a better way to set this within Xcode, but in the iOS Simulator app you can go to Hardware > Device and select the screen size you want.