# UITableViewController headerview not show properly

Tags: uitableview, ios7, interface-builder

The code is pretty streight forward:

```
HGUserInfoHeaderView *headerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView"
                                                                 owner:self
                                                               options:nil] firstObject];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView;
```

And the `HeadView` nib file is like this:[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIrTf.png)

But it turns out to be like this:[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFLkz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for several hours today,finally I found out that I need to wrap the headerview with a dummy view,the code is like this:

```
HGUserInfoHeaderView *headerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"HeaderView"
                                                                 owner:self
                                                               options:nil] firstObject];

UIView *dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 130)];
[dummyView addSubview:headerView];

self.tableView.tableHeaderView = dummyView;
```

And then the header view shows properly:[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hE33E.png).
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24148897/2122622) also helped me,but the question is quite different.
So I decide to post my problem and solution here in case anyone need it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the gray background?

If so, your NIB is incomplete. The headerView is transparent or uses clearColor instead of white.

For issues like this, you could use [SparkInspector](http://sparkinspector.com/).