# Creating a "self-sizing" UITableViewHeaderView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

OK, a really simple version of this that breaks...

Create a `UIView` in a nib.

Add an `imageView` to it. Give the image view a constraint for an Aspect Ratio of 1:1.

Now add constraints from the image view to the edge of the view. (0 size to pin it to the edges).

Now add the view as a UITableView `tableHeaderView`.

When you run the application on different devices it will break the constraints and remove the aspect ratio constraint. I don't want this, I want it to change the height of the view to be equal to the width.

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.   Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.   Try this:       (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;       (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.  (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad01efbbe0 UIImageView:0x7fad047209b0.width == UIImageView:0x7fad047209b0.height>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad04703630 H:[UIImageView:0x7fad047209b0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':VenueHeaderView:0x7fad047204c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad04703680 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fad047209b0]   (Names: '|':VenueHeaderView:0x7fad047204c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad04703740 V:[UIImageView:0x7fad047209b0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':VenueHeaderView:0x7fad047204c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad04703790 H:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7fad047209b0]   (Names: '|':VenueHeaderView:0x7fad047204c0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad0429bcf0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[VenueHeaderView:0x7fad047204c0(300)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad0429bca0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[VenueHeaderView:0x7fad047204c0(375)]>" )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fad01efbbe0 UIImageView:0x7fad047209b0.width == UIImageView:0x7fad047209b0.height>
```

It seems that there are constraints `UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height` being added to the superview. But these are added with the wrong value. It should recalculate these based on the internal constraints of the header view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using autolayout in a tableHeaderView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079591/using-autolayout-in-a-tableheaderview)

Comment: there are many different questions around the topic, if you do a search you'll surely find one that fits your needs.
Basically the idea is to compute the height using autolayout and reset your tableview's tableheaderview frame and view.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried searching before and found many of the "solutions" that the linked answer found. I'll take a look at the answer to that one.

Comment: [self.header setNeedsLayout];
    [self.header layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: @KumarUtsav Hah, nice try. I guess you've tried it and also clicked the link in the comment above? If not, what was the point?

Comment: I had a similar problem today ended up adding less priority to certain constrains, the warning went away