# Autosizing UITableView inside custom UIView for section

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created UIViewController and added UITableView on it (pinned to all four edges with autolayout).

Then I set `estimatedRowHeight` (44) and `rowHeight` (`UITableViewAutomaticDimension`) and returned 5 custom cells. And it worked.

Now, I want to add custom `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` that would have dynamic height.

I'm doing next:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 88.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return R.nib.orderStatusHeaderView.firstView(owner: self)!
}
```

My OrderStatusHeaderView is a xib view that has UITableView on it pinned to all 4 edges with autolayout.

`OrderStatusHeaderView`:

```
final class OrderStatusHeaderView: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.rowHeight = 44.0
        }
    }
}
extension OrderStatusHeaderView: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "\(indexPath.row)")
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
        return cell
    }
}
```

This displays like:

[image]

And when I tap or scroll, all red cells disappears. What could it be? And how to make `UITableView` dynamically load content and `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` will size itself so it fit `UITableView.contentSize`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out:

[tableView(_:estimatedHeightForFooterInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614939-tableview)

and

[tableView(_:heightForFooterInSection:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614967-tableview)

You also have the equilavant for headerInSection.

Comment: Yes, it seems great. I've made it to display.
But the problem is that: 
In `tableView(_:heightForFooterInSection:)` I return `header.tableView.contentSize.height`. But the content is not calculated yet, it uses `header.tableView` estimated height for row and calculates the overall `contentSize.height` as `numberOfRows * estimatedRowHeight`. But the actual size of row is `UITableViewAutomaticDimensions`.

Comment: @OlexiyPyvovarov The point of this method is to know what to set as "contentSize" height (cell height), so asking it to set the contentSize height as the height of course returns 0. If you want to "autosize" you need to either go with UITableViewAutomaticDimensions or calculate the height manually in a method and return it there.

Comment: the size is not calculated because the rows haven't been displayed yet, I suppose.

But I manually created a method that calculates the whole content size with dynamic rows height and it worked Thanks!

Comment: @OlexiyPyvovarov Great! I recommend you keep it that, in my opinion the automaticdimension method is not that very precise or effective, maybe works for some stuff tho, dunno.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for a table's header and footer view, you can skip the delegate methods you describe. Those (as the name implies) are for SECTION headers and footers.

When you set a view that is using AutoLayout as the table's header or footer, the its frame still has a zero height (That's why buttons in such view for example won't work as they are not receiving the touches).

To correctly size a table's header or footer views using AutoLayout you have to apply a trick to actually calculate the height yourself, and set the headerView again. It is described in detail in many posts like these:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28102157/756039
https://gist.github.com/marcoarment/1105553afba6b4900c10
http://collindonnell.com/2015/09/29/dynamically-sized-table-view-header-or-footer-using-auto-layout/
http://roadfiresoftware.com/2015/05/how-to-size-a-table-header-view-using-auto-layout-in-interface-builder/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, I'm a bit confused :) I need section header, not the whole table view header. Doest the answer still applies?

Comment: Well a quick search turns up this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29763200/756039

Comment: @OlexiyPyvovarov Did you not see my answer regarding how to set header and footer heights in sections?