# UIView not filling table views tableHeaderView property swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiview

I have a very peculiar situation and want to know why its happening. I have an edit box and button in a view that I put into a tableview's tableHeaderView property. I call this view InputToListCell.

Now when the view extends UIView I get the following:

[image]

i.e all I change in the code is:

```
class InputToListCell: UIView{
   //Code Here
}
```

I then change InputToListCell to extend UITableViewCell and get the following:

[image]

i.e

```
class InputToListCell: UITableViewCell{
   //Code Here
}
```

Why is this behaviour occurring? I cant see why because UITableViewCell extends UIView. Any thoughts?

Update:

Based on a comment made here are the constraints for the InputToListCell:

[image]

I basically pin both the edit text's and Add buttons constraints to the margin, except for the edit text's trailing value.

Comment: Could have to do with how your Autolayout constraints are set on InputToListCell. Can you update your question with some info about that?

Comment: Pleasa add your cellForRowAtIndexPath method implementation and constraints for cell subviews

Comment: Did the proposed solution not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**In short**

Use `UITableViewCell` for table view elements.

```swift
self.tableView.tableHeaderView =
    tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("sectionIdentifier")
```

---

**Discussion**

Using `UITableViewCell` objects for all table view elements not only provide an umbrella behavior when presented inside a `UITableView`, but will also allow loading from a `.storyboard` or `.xib`, an added bonus and cohesion.

Thus, even though `tableHeaderView` (and `viewForHeaderInSection` for that matter) is informally just a `UIView`, you can return a `UITableViewCell`. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21099430/218152), to take advantage of Autolayout in tableHeaderView, you need to do a bit of gymnastics:

```swift
if let tableHeaderView = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableHeaderViewIdentifier") {
    tableHeaderView.setNeedsLayout()
    tableHeaderView.layoutIfNeeded()

    let height = tableHeaderView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    var frame = tableHeaderView.frame

    frame.size.height = height
    tableHeaderView.frame = frame
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView
}
```

*From a different post:*

[image: Two Section Headers]

---

For a complete example on how to use `.storyboard` or `.xib` for headers, including an Xcode project, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/32261262/218152